# Per vertex shading vs per fragment shading on large models

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am new to GLSL and writing a small application that will show a 3d model and has some user input to rotate, zoom etc. The models are rather big  ( e.g. 6 million vertices, 15million faces). Right now, I am using per vertex shading and performance is ok on my personal pc. But I might need to use larger models ( with 10-15 million vertices).

The question I have is related to the performance comparison between per-vertex and per-fragment shading. From severeal resources, as well as searching the net, I have come to the conclusion that per-fragment is shading has better output especially for specular highlights however its performance is lower since it makes calculations for each pixel of the polygons instead of each vertex ( as in per vertex shading).

Maybe I am thinking completely wrong, but if the vertex count is large , should I expect per fragment shading to run faster for example in my case ( 6-10 million vertex) ? Isthe perforamnce of per fragment shading dependent on the number of pixels that is being drawn to the screen whereas per vertex shading is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance of fragment shading depends on the number of fragments drawn on screen, including those that are drawn twice or more often because some triangles overlap others and overdraw occurs.
Z-buffering can somehow reduce overdraw, but not perfectly. Deferred (or light prepass) shading may still have overdraw during the relatively cheap Z pass, but more or less makes the *actual* shading part strictly proportional of the screen area, irrespective of whether some triangles overlapped (or how many of them were there).

The performance of vertex shading (and following stages) depends mainly on the number of vertices (and some other details if you have a geometry shader or tesselation shader active). Generally, most applications are not limited by vertex processing nowadays. Some millions of vertices *as such* are normally not a problem (though of course not drawing what can't be seen is always better).
However, as triangles become smaller (approaching the size of 2x2 fragment quads), a higher vertex count induces, as a secondary effect, additional fragment shading work (and, of course, assembly/rasterization work, and ROP) without any improved visual quality, sometimes even with inferior quality due to temporal aliasing.
This is not so much related to the actual number of vertices processed, but to the screen area of individual triangles becoming smaller.

Therefore, you should have a LOD (level of detail) system which makes sure that there are not too many too small triangles (for example on far away features), and if those large models are buildings or such you might consider a portal system to clip away entire hierarchies of geometry that don't contribute to the visible result anyway.

Comment: In theory, if you have 6 millions of subfragment (subpixel) triangles - fragment shading could be faster because it will never be executed, while geometry/vertex processing will happen all the way along (don't doing anything is faster than doing _something_). So it continues idea "don't draw anything that have no effect on resulting image".

Comment: Not necessarily, the rasterizer generates a fragment for every raster grid cell that a triangle "touches" (which necessarily is at least one). Unluckily, no such thing as a single fragment exists. Which means the pixel shader runs for a 2x2 group of fragments (this is necessary a) because hardware is simply built to work that way and b) because of derivative calculation). So, 3 vertices produce 4 shaded fragments (presumably with texture lookups and such) that that add nothing to visual quality and end up being discarded or weighted so low that their contribution is not visible.

Comment: In the worst case, a fragment-sized (or smaller) triangle touches 3 fragments that belong to 3 different 2x2 screen quads. Now 3 vertices cause 12 fragments being shaded that do nothing...

Comment: With multisampling - maybe, but without it - they should be discarded before fragment shader execution, just because there is nothing shader can change to prevent discard, so this kind of tests is earlier. But surely it isn't guaranteed, just usual performance optimisation in hardware. About 2x2 - exactly, and it could be larger (i remember some graphics cards with 4x4 execution quads).

Comment: @Damon: your description is incorrect. Fragments get processed if _the center_ of the pixel is covered. for MSAA, it is if _any sample location_ is covered. see pic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for some (DX based) examples.

Comment: thanks all for your replies and comments. as i am new to terminology, i couldnt quite catch the discussion, however, i feel things are getting more solid now. As for the application, I will continue to use it as it is because of deadlines. But i think i need to read more about graphics pipeline. But i didnt get this part(maybe novice :) ) : when polygons are being drawn some cannot pass the depth test, and do they still cause fragments to be reprocessed?

Comment: Sometimes, this depends. Strictly by the standard, depth test happens _after_ the fragment shader. However, if depth is not modified, the implementation can use the interpolated depth and do the test before. Further, if the buffer has been properly cleared and the test conditions haven't been reversed mid-frame, most implementations will nowadays do a hierarchical depth test to reject fragments even earlier. For best results, you want to clear the depth buffer (instead of overwriting) and draw big occluders first, closest to farthest.